# Is there a limit of JPanel to be displayed on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am having some trouble when I add JPanels to a JFrame. My JFrame has a GridBagLayout where I add these JPanels in an horizontal manner, I tested it with two cases, the first one displayed 55 JPanels disposed in a row with a scroll bar, the second one did not worked at all, it had to display 76 JPanels but the result is a very weird one:

[image]

I am not posting code because I think it has nothing to do with the code, maybe is the limit of GUI programming with Swing. I could not find any information about this (the limit) or the same issue that is happening to me.

Thank you

## EDIT

Okay I worked on the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestingFrame extends JPanel {

    public TestingFrame() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;


        int numOfPanels = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPanels; ++i) {
            JPanel toAdd = new JPanel();
            JButton tmp = new JButton("HELLO IT'S ME");

            toAdd.add(tmp);

            gbc.gridx = i;
            this.add(toAdd, gbc);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        TestingFrame view = new TestingFrame();

        JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(view);

        frame.add(scrPane);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This code reproduces the error I was telling you before. Note that more panels were needed to reproduce the error due to the number of components of the JPanels I am using right now, they are smaller than the original ones (just one button).

Comment: "I am not posting code because I think it has nothing to do with the code..." -- how can you make this assumption when you don't know the cause of the problem yet?

Comment: And without seeing code, I cannot tell you what the problem is, but I can give odds based on my own personal experience with bugs: 99.999% of the time the problem is with my own code, and not a problem with Java itself. I'm betting that your odds are similar to mine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sure, 99.999999999% of the times the problem is mine, but I was guessing this time not. Working on making independent the code, or some similar code that induces the same error, as soon as I got it I will post it.

Comment: That's a wise decision

Comment: Your GUI looks to have painting artifacts, something that sometimes occurs if the code blocks the event thread on creation

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry? You say that maybe there's some thread preemption? That would be hard to debug I guess? Btw, I posted code that reproduces the error :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why is this "on hold" ? I posted the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable piece of code. Wasn't this what you wanted to verify that this happens?

Comment: Voting to re-open the question, but having said and done that, your code does not reproduce a problem for me.

Comment: Even increasing 'numOfPanels'? What O.S are you using?